# KendoUI Grid single click dropdown activation

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently when I want to pick an item from a list in my grid I have to click twice.

First click makes the dropdown selector appear, second click opens up the list so I can pick an item.

How do I make it so I only have to click once to activate the dropdown selector and open the list?

Comment: Not that easy since you first have to set the row in edit mode which means a change on how the element is displayed and only then is when you can choose the element from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the **[edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-edit)** event of the Grid and the **[open](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#events-open)** method of the DropDownList.enter link description here

e.g.

```
edit:function(e){
    var ddl = e.container.find('[data-role=dropdownlist]').data('kendoDropDownList');
    if(ddl){
       ddl.open();
    }
},
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ageroy/2/edit) is live example.

Comment: Thanks! Nice drop in solution.